# Limit the number of concurrent sessions per user on PassportJS

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, passport.js

As the title sais, I need to set a upper limit for concurrent sessions per user for a web app to prevent account sharing.

I'm using local strategy in passportjs (on node platform) for authentication.

What is the best practice to do so? Is counting the number of login requests (where the sessions are being created) enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding another field to the session's table for keeping track of `user_id`s.

At each login action which the sessions are being created, I query all the sessions for the current user and delete them if they are over the limit.

Answer (score 1):

For each successful login, you will need to maintain a session record in your database. When someone attempts to login, you will need to query the database to count the number of active sessions.

Your idea of counting the number of login requests doesn't work for a few reasons:

1. If the server restarts, the count would be lost, whereas the users would still be authenticated.
2. It does not scale with multiple Node processes, as each Node process will have no way of communicating login attempts to other processes.

Comment: When I said counting I meant keeping it on the database.

Comment: Any ideas how to deal with the expired sessions?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I can go with whatever I need. Say SQL Server.

Comment: Well with a SQL database, you'll need to construct a query to delete any expired sessions from the database, and run that query any time you care about sessions. You'd have an "expiresAt" field, so you'd have logic to delete all sessions where expiresAt < currentTime. If you were using something like MongoDB, you could take advantage of its time-to-live feature, and have documents auto-delete based on some logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to see if I could come up a cleaner solution and will update. Thanks.

Comment: The alternative would be to just leave the expired sessions in there, and have a job that runs periodically to clean them up. Instead, your session look up query would only retrieve records where expiresAt > currentTime. This increases the complexity of your application as you'll need to use this logic whenever writing any queries related to sessions.

Comment: I'm looking for a clean approach which does not require a job constantly running on the server. I need to define a condition that trig this procedure to save performance.